# Edited DataTable is not updating in Shiny Module

Tags: datatable, module, shiny

I would like to embed numericInput and checkBoxInput in a data table. I have an example from Xie Yihui that works perfectly fine. Exactly like what I wanted.
But when the code is wrapped in a module, the edited table does not update. I read that this could be due to namespace but I do not know how to fix it.

Here are the Gists:

[Gist: edit DataTable in Shiny App](https://gist.github.com/tellyshia/dd1d71ccc0551f60aa4fa14ce4ecb382)

[Gist: edit DataTable in Shiny Module](https://gist.github.com/tellyshia/162b8a43849c25666e4f38c997d66db3)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

There was just one little fix, which is of course hard to see if you're not familiar with Shiny modules. Every **Input ID** you create in the Module Server function has to be wrapped in `ns` (as you do in the UI), but this function is hidden in `session$ns` in the server function. So in line 18, where the inputs are created, their ID had to be adjusted using `session$ns`. From

```
inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
```

to

```
inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(session$ns(id), i), label = NULL, ...))
```

Full code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


editTableUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    DT::dataTableOutput(ns('x1')),
    verbatimTextOutput(ns('x2'))
  )
}

editTable <- function(input, output, session) {
  # create a character vector of shiny inputs
  shinyInput = function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
    inputs = character(len)
    for (i in seq_len(len)) {
      inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(session$ns(id), i), label = NULL, ...))
    }
    inputs
  }



  # obtain the values of inputs
  shinyValue = function(id, len) {
    unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
      value = input[[paste0(id, i)]]
      if (is.null(value)) NA else value
    }))
  }

  # a sample data frame
  res = data.frame(
    v1 = shinyInput(numericInput, 100, 'v1_', value = 0),
    v2 = shinyInput(checkboxInput, 100, 'v2_', value = TRUE),
    v3 = rnorm(100),
    v4 = sample(LETTERS, 100, TRUE),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

  # render the table containing shiny inputs
  output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(
    res, server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, options = list(
      preDrawCallback = JS('function() {
                           Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
      drawCallback = JS('function() {
                        Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
      )
      )
  # print the values of inputs
  output$x2 = renderPrint({
    data.frame(v1 = shinyValue('v1_', 100), v2 = shinyValue('v2_', 100))
  })
      }

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    editTableUI("test")
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    callModule(editTable, "test")
  }
)
```